# Symfony/Twig Set variables in if condition

Tags: symfony, twig

I know this is really trivial and not that important but it could save me some lifetime...
You know you can declare variables in PHP in a if block

```
if( $row = $sql->fetch ){
    //do something with the $row if $row = null this part is skipped
}
```

In twig I can't do for example (set image = object.image, if my object has no image, the variable image becomes null and the if statement does not become true

```
{% if image = object.image %}
    <img src="{{ image.getUrl() }}"> //and so on
{% endif %}
```

Instead I have to make it this way (check if the object has an image, if yes save it to new variable and do some stuff with it)

```
{% if object.image %}
    {% set image = object.image %}
    <img src="{{ image.getUrl() }}"> //and so on
{% endif %}
```

Of course I know this is no first world problem and you may think my question is useless but I have to write those "longer" statements many times a day so I could be few minutes faster  in the end.
So is there a syntax that allows me to set variables in an if block instead of comparing them?

Thank you very much

**EDIT**
I't the same like this [Can I define a variable in a PHP if condition?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6741399/can-i-define-a-variable-in-a-php-if-condition) just in twig

Comment: If you have lots of the same code you should consider using includes / macro's / extending twig with a `Twig_SimpleFunction` or `Twig_SimpleFilter`

Comment: Can you post a *real life example*, without "and so on", to make your problem more apparent?

Comment: you can remove the set part and just use `<img src="{{ object.image.url }}">`

Comment: @mickdev I know but we mostly have long constructs so in the end I would have something like `entry->lnkSomeFieldName->first()->lnkCategory->first()->image->first()->getUrl()` and the same with the title if I would not separate it that way

Comment: @YourCommonSense I don't know why it should be important what I do after that... I just want to declare my variables in a if condition like in php

Comment: @DarkBee a macro won't work since you can't return something in macros as far as I know

Comment: @Anubarak it's up to you. If you want a good answer that solves your problem at whole, not just a partial solution that is too specific to the hasty sketch you posted - then it's better to post the actual code. If you don't want a solution but just to show off - well, your code is enough.

Comment: @Anubarak What do mean? [snippet](https://twigfiddle.com/lfuh9p)

Comment: @YourCommonSense I don't know what this has to do with a certain "problem" it's just a simple syntax question like "how can I shorten this code in php"? `$var = $var + 1` answer: `$var++`. I have the feeling you missunderstood me. In every other language `if (variable = value) is not a comparison but a declaration and sets variable to value. But twig gives me an error when I do this way. My only question is if there is a syntax that allows it

Comment: @DarkBee http://craftcms.stackexchange.com/questions/10065/use-a-twig-macro-to-set-a-variable macros can only render code and are not able to set/return variables. Its not only about images, it`s about every single parent-child relation that I have to check. And there are a lot of them in CraftCMS

Comment: @Anubarak [updated snippet](https://twigfiddle.com/lfuh9p)

Comment: @Anubarak like I said, it is *entirely* up to you. You have to understand that you need a real code example not for me. I don't care actually. I just suggested it for you, in case you want to get an answer. But of course it's up to you. Cheers :)

Comment: @DarkBee thank you but this does not solve my problem at all... Its not about images, its about declaring a variable in an if block. Its just about syntax. it would take much longer to create a macro for every single parent child relation than just make 2 lines instead of 1.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

No, there is no way to declare a variable inside an `if` tag. Variables can only be set using the `set` tag.

Comment: What a pity, thank you. It seems you are the only person who understood me

Comment: @Anubarak other persons tried to solve the *problem*. But, like I said, you don't want to solve a problem but only to show off. Not that I am blaming you for that but I'd like to ask you not to blame people who tried to help.

Comment: I don't see how you tried to help me... you just said you don't care and need an example but Xabbuh had no code and helped me the most. Honestly I don't really get what you mean with "other persons tried to solve the problem" I just wanted to know if there is a syntax for it or not. I appreciate the help from DarkBee since he tried to create me a workaround.

Answer (score 6):

You can set it with a ternary operator.

`{% set result =  condition ? "a": "b" %}`

Comment: That will only do it in certain cases but most of the time not since you need an additional check if result is empty or not. That was the main concern.

Answer (score 0):

Setting a variable based on a condition is absolutely possible!

```
{% set variable = (condition == 1) ? 'this' : 'that' %}
```

The condition can be evaluated against `true`, `false`, or another variable as well.

Comment: Thank you, but that was not the question and was already said before.

Answer (score -1):

You can use (check [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3264889/how-to-check-for-null-in-twig) for more help) :

```
{% if object.image is defined or object.image is not null %}
   <img src="{{ image.url }}">
{% endif %}
```

Hope this helps !

Comment: His question is how to reduce the amount of code, not how to extend it even more

Comment: True, I did not take the time to fully understand the question, indeed! I was too focused on how to find the answer. Sorry...

Comment: How can one find the answer if he does not see the question?